# How to remove list items comparing with another list items of same type

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following class:

```
class Detail
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set;}
    public List<Transaction> tran { get; set; }
}
```

I have two list of Detail type: ListA & ListB.

Which is the fastest way to remove items from ListA that exist in ListB?

Comment: When is one details instance equal to other?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can do it using following code with better performance:

```
var oListBHashSet = new HashSet<Detail>(ListB);
ListA.RemoveAll(v => oListBHashSet.Contains(v));
```

Using HashSet makes Contains check fast, and ensures that sequence evaluated only once.

Answer (score 4):

First you should define what *equals* means, then you can write something like this

```
var result = ListA.Except(ListB, new Comparer());
```

---

```
public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<Detail>
{

    public bool Equals(Detail x, Detail y)
    {
        return x.Name == y.Name
                && x.State == y.State
                && x.City == y.City
                && x.tran.SequenceEqual(y.tran);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Detail obj)
    {
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

PS: same *equality question* is also true for `Transaction` object

Answer (score 0):

The "fastest" way is going to depend on a lot of variables including how big the lists are.  If there are a small number of items then the fastest way will likely be a simple search

```
ListA.RemoveAll(i => !ListB.Contains(i));
```

If there are a higher number of elements then you may want to use an intermediate structure like a `HashSet<Detail>` to speed up the lookup process

```
var set = nwe HashSet<Detail>(ListB);
ListA.RemoveAll(i => !set.Contains(i));
```

The lookup speed on a `HashSet<Detail>` is considerably faster than `List<Detail>`.  However there is a cost to building up the `HashSet<Detail>` value.  When dealing with small number of elements the time to build up the structure may outweigh its benefits.  Which one is faster for you can only be determined by profiling your code